# Send arguments containing ${xxx} to bash/expect script

Tags: bash, lua, expect, u-boot

I am currently working with **Expect** and in order to automate some processes in **U-Boot** of my board.

My expect script sends U-Boot commands and gets triggered from a Lua script.

Excerpt from the expect script **ExpectScript.sh**:

```
set device [lindex $argv 0]
set sendCmd [lindex $argv 1]

spawn minicom $device
send "$sendCmd\n"
```

Excerpt from the lua script:

```
assert(io.popen("ExpectScript.sh myDevice \"setenv firstBlock \"nand erase 0x0 0x80000 && nand write.i ${loadaddr} 0x0 ${filesize}\"\""))
```

Generally sending commands this way works. However, in this particular case listed here, parts of the string are variables ( **${loadaddr}** and **${filesize}** (for this variable imagine that I got a file before via nfs or tftp)) which only exist in **U-Boot**.

So when printing the environment via **printenv** in **U-Boot** I see:

```
firstBlock=nand erase 0x0 0x80000 && nand write.i  0x0
```

instead of:

```
firstBlock=nand erase 0x0 0x80000 && nand write.i ${loadaddr} 0x0 ${filesize}
```

Any ideas of how to get also the parts of the string containing the variables, e.g. **${loadaddr}**, through my layers of programs?

Comment: Single quotes in shell are "dont-touch-anything-inside".  Use them instead of double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Solution is the following: `assert(io.popen('ExpectScript.sh myDevice \"setenv firstBlock \'nand erase 0x0 0x80000 && nand write.i \\${loadaddr} 0x0 \\${filesize}\'\"'))`   "\\" is required to escape the "$" sign twice. (once for expect and once for U-Boot I guess)

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write *Expect* scripts with shell code only.

Answer (score 0):

To display the contents of U-Boot variables you can use the echo command, e.g.

```
echo ${fdt_addr_r}
```

So use a first step in your script to verify the variable contents and a second step to execute the respective command.